# Combining CSS animation with JQuery while keeping its smoothness

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am trying to build a traditional slots machine using CSS3 and jQuery but I have come to some issues. I started off with a CSS3 Animation which runs infinitely until someone triggers an event (a button or such similar). Before we go any further, here is the CSS:

```
@keyframes animation-one {
  100% {
      margin-top: -960px;
  }
}

.slots-one {
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-left: 7.5px solid #38465a;
  animation: animation-one 2s linear infinite;
}
```

It is meant to play indefinitely until that event is triggered and then I would like to transition smoothly to a dynamic number of choice. I couldn't see how I would do this in CSS so I decided to mix in some jQuery and here was my result:

```
.slots-one {
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-left: 7.5px solid #38465a;
}
.anim-one {
  animation: animation-one 2s linear infinite;
}

/*in order for the animation to be smooth, i needed to maintain the same speed.
 i know the height of the div is 1150px with a -5 margin-top so i divided the
 seconds of the current animation (2) by the total height then 
 multiplied it with the new dynamic height i wanted to enforce. */

var seconds = (2 / 1150) * 750; //750 being a random number between 0 and 1150

var margin = -5-750;

$('.board.slots-one').on('animationiteration', function () {
  $(this).removeClass('anim-one')
         .animate({
           "margin-top": margin+"px"
         }, seconds.toString()+"s", "linear") //i figured that an easing wouldn't look too good.
})
```

And like I expected, the animation was choppy and didn't mix the way I wanted it to. I left some references to the animations on the bottom.

---

References:
[CSS3 Animation](https://media.giphy.com/media/l0Ex5EXEiTpUHjoZ2/source.gif)

[CSS3 Animation + jQuery Animation](https://media.giphy.com/media/l3q2UTuLYhMEzEWM8/source.gif)

---

So my question would be 1) if this is even possible and if so how can I achieve this? And 2) if it isn't what are my alternatives? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery to set the `margin-top` and a CSS `transition` to control the timing.

Like this:

```
$('.board.slots-one').on('animationiteration', function () {
    $(this)
    .removeClass('anim-one')
    .css({
        'margin-top': margin,
        'transition': 'all ' + seconds.toString() + 's linear'
    })
}
```

Comment: Already tried it. Transitions don't seem to work on `$.css`. Not sure why.

Comment: Only in that scenario they don't.

Comment: The best alternative is the GreenSock https://greensock.com/. It`s way smoother than jquery, for sure.